# What types of words can be appended to a keyword to produce a legible phrase?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, nouns, adjectives, adverbs

I'm creating a random business name generator. For example if I provide the word: cars, the generator will create a handful of random words such as:

- robot cars
- cars united
- penny cars
- cars delight

As you can see the word cars is either appended, or pre-appended, to another word. I've figured I can use nouns and appened my original word to create a readable random name. Ie: penny cars.

But, what types of words can be used to produce words such as: cars delight, where the original word is pre-appened?

I'm trying to do something similar to what shopify do: https://www.shopify.co.uk/tools/business-name-generator

Correctness isn't an issue so long as the generated words make sense grammatically. There's software libraries I can use such as RitaJS to attempt to validate readability and decide where to use it or not.

Words I consider to be readable (even if they make no sense):

- housing list
- housing lead
- housing officer
- social housing
- free housing
- cedar housing
- strawberry housing
- snake housing

Words I consider to be incorrect:

- ladders housing
- potatoes housing
- housing delightfully
- housing running
- housing because
- housing willing

The incorrect words make no sense because they are not readable.

Answer (score 2):

What are are asking for is very complicated, and not really about grammar. There is not going to be a straightforward rule to determine the 'correctness' of any phrase generated in this way. You haven't even clearly stated what you mean by 'correct'.

Let's assume for now that your base word is always a noun. English has the concept of a '[noun string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_string)', which is "a series of nouns or other words, all of which modify the final noun". This is what you get when you prepend (not pre-append) the word 'robot' to get 'robot cars. The objects are cars, and 'robot' tells you what kind of cars they are.

Any string of nouns is grammatically correct. But that doesn't mean they all make sense. 'robot cars' makes sense, but 'existentialism cars', 'incompatibility cars' or 'delight cars' (for example) don't. But you can't tell that by analyzing the grammatical structure. It's just that the concepts don't belong together. You could imagine a world in which the concepts did belong together, and then the phrase would make sense.

You can also prepend an adjective to a noun and get a grammatically correct phrase. So 'blue cars', 'lovely cars' or 'motivated cars' make grammatical sense, if not necessarily much else. You could also prepend a verb to a noun, as a imperative ("destroy cars") or progressive ("parking cars"), or append one in any tense in the third person ('cars advance', 'cars retreated').

Correctness of these phrases is about semantics, not grammar, and that is really outside the scope of this site. You might like to read '[colourless green ideas sleep furiously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)' as a starting point.

To pick on the examples you give "ladders housing" (which you consider incorrect) is exactly the same grammatical construction as "cedar housing", which you consider correct. To emphasize again, your idea of 'correctness' is all about semantics, and nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: Correctness is not important. I'm looking to do what Shopify have done with their business name generator. Some of their suggestions are meaningless and I assume that's because of the difficulty in generating correct names because of the issues you've mentioned above.

Comment: If correctness is not important than you can pair any two words together.

Comment: Grammatical correctness is important. Making sense isn't important.

Comment: I would hazard the assumption that there is no such thing as "grammatical correctness" if limited to just two words. Especially if they should name something. It is probably a lot easier to create a database of words you randomly put around the entered term.

Comment: @Helmar that's kind of what I am doing but I was hoping to increase the likelihood of getting a good word. I now understand the difficulties in the question I'm asking though.